# ebtables emulate "redirect" rule in brouting

Tags: linux, iptables, redirection, bridge

I want to be able to redirect all traffic which have a specific destination IP (say 192.168.168.192), passing through a software bridge on Linux (br1), to localhost.

As far as I understood I need to do something like:

`ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-dst 192.168.168.192 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP`

and then DNAT-ing/SNAT-ing via iptables.

The problem is that the device on which I am trying to configure it seems to not support the `-j redirect` part. Is there any way (without recompiling the kernel) to do the same with help of iptables/ebtables? For example doing:

`ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-dst 192.168.168.192 -j DROP`

And then do some iptables magic?

Comment: Just read the description of the `redirect` target in `man ebtables`. For BROUTING you can replace the `redirect` target with multiple `dnat` targets that will specify the incoming bridge port's MAC (so one rule per bridge port ). Hope this helps. I'm not sure about the overall method though, but I don't have much experience on this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I think I'll try to look into DNAT-ing. That's actually good enough for me as I need to redirect only packets from one bridge port.